# How can I find items with multiple variables from items in another array?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have two collections: `Logs` and `Metadatas`. They both have the fields `hash` and `application`.

I have an array of relevant `Metadatas` that I've projected to look like this:

`{ hash: string, application: string }[]`

Each combination of `{ hash, application }` is unique within that array. My goal is to find any `Logs` whose combination of `application` and `hash` exist as an item within that array.

So I essentially need to do something like this:

```
Logs.find(
   { 
      application: { $in: <one particular item from the array>},
      hash: <the hash from the SAME item from that array>
   }
);
```

This can be done in my JavaScript, but the collections may be very large, and I'd rather offload it to MongoDB directly. Is there a best way to go about this kind of query?

I've tried a few different types of aggregation, but cannot find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of making one query for the whole array, you can make a query per item to solve this easily:

```
const logs = await Promise.all(
  metadatas.map(metadata => Logs.findOne(metadata))
)
```

The number of queries is linear to the size of your in-memory metadata array and all queries are performed concurrently so the complexity should be `O(timeOfTheLongestQuery)`

If there are more logs that can match the `{ application, hash }` tuple, use `find` instead of `findOne`:

```
const logs = await Promise.all(
  metadatas.map(metadata => Logs.find(metadata))
)
```

This will give you a 2D array which you can flatten:

```
const logs = flatten(await Promise.all(
  metadatas.map(metadata => Logs.find(metadata))
))
```

Or convert to a `Map<application + hash, listOfLogs>` if you need to process it later using the same data:

```
const logsMap = new Map(await Promise.all(
  metadatas.map(async metadata => [
    JSON.stringify(metadata), // can use a different stringification strategy here
    await Logs.find(metadata)
  ])
))
```